# How to assign a unique identifier to an instance in python

Tags: python, instance, uniqueidentifier

I am working with xls files. From each file i extract (after some processing) several 1D arrays, each is assigned to an instance of a costume class, which also holds some relevant parameters which serve to distinguish between various configurations under which the data in the xls files was obtained.

I wish to sort the above instances into a data structure which contains a dictionary whose keys are the **UNIQUE DESIGNATORS** and the values are the corresponding instances.

The rest of the data structure is a two level nested default dictionary. The top level keys are the above mentioned parameters, with default factory of a default dictionary. The top level values are therefore also dictionaries, whose keys are the values the parameters may take (unknown initially, hence the use of default dictionary), and default factory of list. The list holds the **UNIQUE DESIGNATORS** of the instances which have a certain value for a certain parameter.

A crucial element is assigning a unique designator to each instance which is inserted into the data structure in order to avoid duplicity and ambiguity. I should emphasize that a solution like uuid would not work as i may need to reprocess the xls files, which may alter the resulting arrays, but leave the parameter's values the same, which in this case requires the identifier to be the same.

The Solution which eventually worked for me was using a 2-tuple of the form (xls file full path, an index number).

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to obtain such a unique identifier.

Comment: Can you share some code that reproduces your case where it didn't work?

Comment: Perhaps creating a `getHash()` method on your `Costume` class that returns the 2-tuple you described? (i.e., `data[ obj.getHash() ] = obj`)

Comment: Did you try hash(str((xls file full path, index of original array))

Comment: You can use the built-in `id()` function on each object instance. It will be unique if none of them are the same object.

Comment: @Mickey Diamant: If there's nothing else that is unique to each costume in your files than the filename/row index information, I think that's the best solutions.

Comment: @advance512 I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Explain what you mean by didn't work? How so? What are your requirements for an identifier? What do you want it to do and doesn't it do?

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with a construct of the form [item]*n. As i wrote, from each xls file i get several curves. I made a "list" of instances of a curve class i designed using [curve(arguments)]*n (where n is the number of needed instances). As i understand, all those instances are exact copies (all point to the same memory segment), so they would return the same result when acted on with the hash function.